# Preventing stickiness in Candy Apples

Tags: candy, apples

I cook the sugar to a hard crack stage 300.  I have used some gel pigments after temp is reached.  The candy coating is perfect for about 3 - 5 minutes and almost instantly begins to get sticky.  I have tried two methods.  One with Karo light syrup and another with Lorann oils high sweet (specifically used for high humidity areas). they both have given same results with stickiness. I have tried to place them in front of fan and has the worst results compared to not having a fan.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [edit] to include your full recipe (how much sugar, how much corn syrup)?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66667/how-do-i-make-candy-apples-not-sticky?rq=1 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82758/sticky-candy-apples?rq=1